# Cannot resolve the collation conflict in Update query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, collation

I got several answers for this error but nothing works in my case.I have a simple update query

```
      update students set studentID  ='001093' where studentID ='1578093'
```

when i am trying to update in my sql db getting this collation error:

```
      Cannot resolve the collation conflict between 
     "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AI" in the equal 
      to operation.
```

what i tried

```
         update students set studentID COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ='001093' where studentID ='1578093'  COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

please help on this problem..i know we have enough duplicates but none of the solution is working for me

Comment: Does your table have a trigger that accesses another table? Does it participate in any views?

Comment: no its an independent table

Answer (score 0):

The collation should be applied to the *string* value, not the column:

```
update students
    set studentID = '001093' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI
    where studentID = '1578093' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI;
```

Comment: not working this one also.1 rows affected msg displaying but not updated ..(1 row(s) affected)
Msg 468, Level 16, State 9, Line 225
Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AI" in the equal to operation.

Comment: @beginer_programer . . . I switched the collations.  You need to use the one that is defined in the table -- and the error message is not clear on which is which.

Comment: just copied the error message from log..tried switching also but no results

Comment: try adding "N" before values, like studentID = N'001093'. it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Good day, beginer_programer.
Try to apply the COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT:

```
   Update students
   SET studentID  ='001093' collate database default
   WHERE studentID  = studentID ='1578093'  collate database default
```

Comment: i have tried this one also but still i am getting the error.There is no dependency with the table

Comment: Please, run this query and tell the result:         
  SELECT SERVERPROPERTY ('Collation')

Comment: Latin1_General_CI_AI -------is the result returning.In my studentID   ,collation column is  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Comment: SELECT col.name, col.collation_name FROM sys.columns col WHERE     object_id = OBJECT_ID('StudentId')----here  student id column,collation is  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Comment: I have changed query, please try again